# Copy/link GitHub repository to a folder

Tags: github, hyperlink, copy, mklink

So I have got a github repo, that I use. I would like that every time it updates (there was a new commit), that those files would copy over to my PC.

I have tried using a mklink in the command prompt, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are contributors other than yourself making commits to the repo, you can use [git fetch](https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/) to retrieve all new commits or contributions to the repo. To get the latest commits, you want to cd into the repo locally on your machine. Run a `git status`, to make sure everything is fine and good to go. If everything is clear, you can run a `git fetch` and that should bring in all of the newest changes into your local repository.

A great way to avoid [merge conflicts](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/), which is the result of having commit overlap while committing and or pushing, is to run a `git pull` before you `git push` your newest commits.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you! It worked when I installed github for my PC. I had been working from chrome only. Thank you!